# Can OS X Expose show hidden applications?

Tags: macos, mac, expose

Is it possible for OS X's Expose to display hidden applications? It currently only shows displayed and minimized windows, hidden application (and their windows) are not displayed.

I'm running OS X 10.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, by design you can't.

However, you can hit the <kbd>tab</kbd> key while using exposé to tab through exposé by application… that will select hidden application windows as well.